# How to keep original text colors, set using setForeground(), when QTableWidgetItem is selected

Tags: python, css, pyside2, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

---

### My Problem:

Right now, as you can see on *Fig 2* below, as the first row is selected, all texts' colors are set to **black**, instead of keeping their original style displayed on *Fig 1*.

Is there a way to keep the original colors when the row is selected (as shown in *Fig 3*)? Should I keep relying on CSS alone or should I just create a `QAbstractItemDelegate` to fix this problem?

If a `QAbstractItemDelegate` is needed, is it faster than using CSS or does it slow down the application?

[image]

*Fig 1: How it looks like without any selection.*

[image]

*Fig 2: How it looks like when user selects Row 0.*

[image]

*Fig 3: Made on Paint, how I would like it to behave.*

---

**Settings:**

I am using PySide2: Qt5 on Python 3.10 on Windows 10.

In my example, I have set a few properties on my `QTableWidget` before inserting rows inside it:

```
self.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.NoDragDrop)
self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
self.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
self.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
self.setShowGrid(False)

tv = self.verticalHeader()
tv.setVisible(False)
tv.setSectionsClickable(False)
tv.setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Fixed)
tv.setDefaultAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)

th = self.horizontalHeader()
th.setHighlightSections(False)
th.setStretchLastSection(True)
th.setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Interactive)

# With Exception to Column 0: ResizeMode is ResizeToContents
```

Then I created a function to easily insert items inside it. It's a big function, which relies on a few methods from `QTableWidget` and `QTableWidgetItem` shown here:

```
# Insert the row at the table, on specified index
self.insertRow(index)

# Get the QTableWidgetItem from row r and column c, and ensure it exists
item = self.item(r, c)
if (item is None):
    item = QTableWidgetItem()
    self.setItem(r, c, item)

# To change the text color, using a QColor
QTableWidgetItem.setForeground()

# To change the text alignment, using Qt Flags
QTableWidgetItem.setTextAlignment() 

# To set the text inside the cell
QTableWidgetItem.setText()
```

My CSS, related to these widgets, is:

```
QTableWidget {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

QTableWidget::item {
    background-color: white;
}

QTableWidget::item:alternate {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* I Have already tried setting 'color: inherit', but there is no effect */
QTableView::item:selected, QTableView::item:alternate:selected {
    background-color: #92b7d1;
}

QHeaderView::section {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

QHeaderView::section:hover {
    background-color: silver;
}
```

**Forgot to mention after posting:** the rounded colored square, on 'Color' Column, is an Unicode Text from FontAwesomes, which I downloaded the OTF file and added to the application using the `QFontDatabase` from PySide2. Basically this guy [here](https://fontawesome.com/v4/icon/square).

Comment: If your issue is just about the colored square, use basic images: plain color images are usually fast and light enough. You can create them easily, just create a QPixmap and fill it: `pm = QPixmap(16, 16)` `pm.fill(<somecolor>)` `item.setIcon(QIcon(pm))` (you can also make rounded squares using QPainter). Alternatively, use QStyledItemDelegate, you cannot set per-item colors with stylesheets.

Comment: Yeah, not exactly that. Actually, it's hard to notice, but the floating number on Area Column is colored with indigo color. When the row is selected, it changes to black as well. I wanted to keep all cells with a different configuration. Some have predefined colors based on their columns, (like the floating number) and others depend on their contents such as the squares (some are red, others are blue or green).

Comment: Now, the QStyleItemDelegate seems a good idea. But I wanted to make sure I couldn't simply set a CSS option so the text wouldn't change it's color to black, when the row is being selected.

Comment: CSS works for generic solutions and selectors, but cannot be used for specific items (and it also completely overrides the foreground/background color of the item if set in the model). Subclass QStyledItemDelegate, then override `initStyleOption()`, call the base implementation, check that the `index.data(Qt.ForegroundRole)` is valid and eventually call `opt.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText), index.data(color).color())`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do just that. I never used Delegates before, that's why I wanted a simpler solution, but yeah it's ok... it will just require further reading on the documentation. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Ok, using `QStyledItemDelegate` solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still wondering, after an year or so, I found out that there exists a [module](https://pypi.org/project/QtAwesome/) that converts FontAwesome (and other sources of) icons into *QIcons* and even *QWidgets*.

Using that module, you can specify a color parameter and change the icon's color at will during its creation. Much, much easier than doing everything I've done on this post.

I recommend checking it out if you're going the through the route of this post.